# how to allow more than 1 rows to appear horizontally

Tags: php, html, css, php-7

This is an example of what I want to achieve
[image: 5 rows used by amazon for products display]

but what I was able to display is 1 product per row.
This is what I have done and but is not working as intended.

```
<ol>
<?php
    $no = 1;
    foreach($projects as $project):?>
        <?php if($project['finish'] == 'no'):?>
            <li><?=$no?></li>
            <li><?=$project['type']?></li>
            <li><?=$project['date_started']?></li>
            <li><?=$project['brief_description']?></li>
            <li><?=$project['full_description']?></li>
            <li>
                <?php foreach($images as $image):?>
                    <?php if($image['project_id'] == $project['id']):?>
                        <img src="img/<?=$image['name']?>">
                    <?php endif;?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact.php?projectid=<?=$project['id']?>" class="button info">Contact admin</a>
            </li>
            <?php endif;?>
                if($no % 5 === 0):
                   echo "<br>";
                endif;
            <?php $no++; ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

How can I get the code to display 5 lists per row

Comment: @ghenba wale I don't know you .I can tell you if you don't accept my answer  I'll find you with my very particular set of skills ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<table>

<?php
echo '<tr>';
for($i=1;$i<100;$i++)
{

    echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';

    if($i%5==0)
    { 
        echo $i;
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }

}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This will you the idea
[image]

Comment: the question is actually about looping and conditional check

Comment: Ok . That's perfectly fine . i was just answering to laying items in rows of 5!